# Error: The page you are trying to access does not exist

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

The page you are trying to access does not exist.
Please select a page from the main menu.

I'm facing the above error on server. Actually the primary website is on joomla now I'm adding one more website like this. http://joomlaweb.com/wordresswebsite and It's working fine but once I change the permalinks Default to Post name. It's shows the error..

Note: The second web is on wordpress.

Please help. I am thinking there is something from .htaccess but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work on wordpress issue
For the wordpress site you have to do in admin section and follow some steps:

> - Step:1 Go to  admin setting.
> - Step:2 Click on permalink and select post name in radio button.
> - Step:3 Scroll down and you will see .htacces code here like.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

> - Step:4 copy the code and paste in the .htaccess file.

Comment: @Rahil Wazir. I already tried the same but after that wordpress is working fine but now the joomla web is not working. :(

Comment: @Tariq I didn't answer your question.

Comment: @Mahesh singh chouhan I already tried the same but after that wordpress is working fine but now the joomla web is not working. :(